# Django | Filter Ordering - How to implement "ordering" when you use @property

Tags: django

please help me to make the correct "ordering" for a "custom" property **some_property_field**. I write such an URL and it doesn't work. I understand the reason is a "custom" property. How to work it out?

/api/articles/?**ordering=-some_property_field**

**urls.py**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'articles', ArticleViewSet, basename='articles')
urlpatterns = []

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def some_property_field(self):
        return f'{self.title} property func'
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'title', 'some_property_field')
    ordering = ('id',)  # default ordering
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    some_property_field = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Update your `route` or `URL`.

Comment: what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Ordering is done in queryset so you can only use field that exists in database.

If you want to order by property you need to do that in python:

```
qs = sorted(Article.objects.all(), key=lambda obj: obj.some_property_field)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: U meant to add here, right?
queryset = sorted(Article.objects.all(), key=lambda obj: obj.some_property_field)

Comment: No. This error occures, because `sorted` returns sorted `list` not `Queryset`. As I said. I'm not aware of any way to sort Queryset using @property. Ordering can be done only on db fields or annotates.

Comment: could u show me how to implement it by annotates?

Comment: You can't order by `@property` even with annotates.